# Mouse left click is colliding with right click routine in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to run these functions but the 'mousedown' events triggers on left and right mouse click. Specifically, how can I integrate these functions just with the left click? I have seen so many examples on the internet but I couldn't make them work. Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Here is the code:

```
    // mouse drag pieces
    boardEl.on('mousedown', '.' + CSS.square, mousedownSquare);
    containerEl.on('mousedown', '.' + CSS.sparePieces + ' .' + CSS.piece, mousedownSparePiece);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adding a data argument to the function you pass to the .on, e.g `event` to the function, you can use `event.which` to determine if it is a left or right click.

```
function mousedownSquare( e ) {
 if (e.which === 1) {
  //handle left click
 }
  if(e.which === 3) {
  //handle right click
 }
}
```

Comment: I was trying to change the event 'mousedown' to a left click specific event but it doesn't exists. But handle the mouse event inside the function being executed works great. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Never used it, but apparently the event object `which` property can get the desired button.

http://api.jquery.com/mousedown/